# How to generate random numbers in ascending or descending order

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,c;

    cout<<"Enter number of items to be sorted: ";
    cin>>n;

    int data[n];

    cout<<"Unsorted Array: \n";
    for (int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        data[x]=rand();
        cout<<data[x]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

This code here generate random numbers with no specific order. How can I make this code to generate random numbers in ascending or descending order.

I already try to search in this forum but what I found is only to generate random numbers with no order.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You generate them first, and sort afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't: they are called **random** for a reason. If you need a sorted array of random numbers, you should populate your array first, then sort it. Also, I would suggest using `std::array` for fixed-size arrays, if you have c++11.

```
std::vector<int> data;
for (int x=0;x<n;x++)
{
    data.push_back(rand());
}

std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Comment: Ok ok, Thank you sir.  I asked this because I need to make random numbers to ascending order to descending order and just thought that it is possible to generate random numbers that is already in ascending or descending.

Thank you for the clarification.

Also thank you for the others who answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
sum=0;
for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
{ 
   sum+=random(100);
   arr[i]=sum;
}
```

Comment: I think an answer like this should be the accepted answer because I feel like this can be done without sorting.  Although when you generate random numbers w/o 100 as the max as in OP's case, you'd have to worry about overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there is a built in solution. Depending on the statistical properties you want, you can either generate n numbers and sort them afterwards or you just add the ne random number to the previous one.

Btw rand is more or less deprecated in c++11. You should rather use the tools from the random header instead.

```
int main() {
    //init generator with number from true random device
    mt19937 gen(random_device{}());
    //define desired distribution equal to what you would get with rand()
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, RAND_MAX);

    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of items to be sorted: ";
    cin >> n;

    //generate numbers
    vector<int> data;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        data.push_back(dist(gen));
    }
    //sort numbers
    sort(begin(data), end(data));

    //print numbers
    for (auto& e : data) {
        cout << e << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it on java without sorting, assuming you want all positive integers (can obviously adjust array length):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rndm = new Random();
    int arrayLength = 10;
    int randOutput;
    int checkAscend;
    //determining array size
    int[] array = new int[arrayLength];
    //populating array with random ascending integers
    for(int i = 0;i < arrayLength;i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
            checkAscend = 0;
        }
        else {
            checkAscend = array[i - 1];
        }
        randOutput = rndm.nextInt();
        if(randOutput > checkAscend) {
            array[i] = randOutput;
        }
        else {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Comment: When a large number is generated, there is a small range of possible new numbers that are larger.  This means there is a small chance the next random int will be large enough, causing the loop to run potentially many times until a number within that small range is produced.  This method is an infinite loop if INT_MAX is generated because no new int will ever be large enough.